# How to upgrade online redis cluster to tls

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am able to set up a non-SSL Redis cluster (3 masters, 3 replicas) easily but I’m having a lot of issues getting my SSL cluster to function.

I want to upgrade the original redis cluster cluster to a tls redis cluster

the non-ssl configuration is :

```
port 7111
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
...
```

the ssl configuration is :

```
port 7111
tls-port 7112
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
tls-cluster yes
tls-auth-clients no
```

i stop all redis servers and try to modify their nodes.conf, 7111->7112 and 17111(communication bus)->17112, and then restart. it's seem to be work, i can use non-tls client 7111 and get key successfully ,also tls client 71112.

but there is some error redis.log show:
Error accepting a client connection: error:1408f10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=21)

Now I wonder, is this upgrade method reasonable?
And how to solve this exception log?